# Conditionally counting nodes in a tree traversal - recursively

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

Working on a University assignment which requires comparing nodes in a tree and making a count of nodes which meet a certain condition. I can see how I could do this iteratively, traversing the tree with a stack etc, but I'm certain the lecturers are looking for a recursive solution and I'm struggling to wrap my head around this particular implementation.

My current (flawed) implementation is:

```
public int traverseIncrement(User user, User reference) {

    if(user == null)
        return 0;

    int count = 1;

    if (user.getLeft() != null) {
        if(user.getLevel() > reference.getLevel()) {
            count += traverseIncrement(user.getLeft(), reference);
        }
    }

    if (user.getRight() != null) {
        if(user.getLevel() > reference.getLevel()) {
            count += traverseIncrement(user.getRight(), reference);
        }
    }

    return count;       
}
```

There are two obvious problems, the first being that the first node is never evaluated and the second being that I am always one higher than the required output. Any nudge in the right direction would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the two problems are related. Rather than assume the `count` is 1 then recurse depending upon whether the condition is met, you should set `count` depending upon the condition, then recurse. In other words, leave the evaluation of a given node up to the call that is handling that node.

Also, you can eliminate the check for left or right being `null` since your function already checks on entry.

```
public int traverseIncrement(User user, User reference) {
    if(user == null)
        return 0;

    int count = (user.GetLevel() > reference.getLevel()) ? 1 : 0;

    count += traverseIncrement(user.getLeft(), reference);
    count += traverseIncrement(user.getRight(), reference);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Ah yep, I'm with you. That's perfect. Thank you for your help :)